Xcode Preview crashes with swift data models with complex relationships
I use the following ModelContainer to have a preview DB, but it crash when I add more than one Model3 (after print "Container Done"). If I reduce model3 at one, It works correctly.
Suggestions on how to better fix or debug the error?
PreviewContainer
@MainActor
let previewContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Model1.self, Model2.self, Model3.self, configurations: ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true))
        
        let cList = [ Model1(name: "Name1") ,Model1(name: "Name2") ,Model1(name: "Name3")]
            
        cList.forEach { c in
            container.mainContext.insert(c)
            c.childModel1 = [Model1(name: "Name1Child"),Model1(name: "Name2Child")]
        }
        
        let aList = [Model2(name: "Name1"),Model2(name: "Name2"),Model2(name: "Name3")]
            
        aList.forEach { a in
            container.mainContext.insert(a)
        }
        
        let tList = [ Model3(amount: Int.random(in: 0...2000000), Model3(amount: Int.random(in: 0...2000000) ]

            
        tList.forEach { t in
            container.mainContext.insert(t)
            t.model2 = aList[0]
            t.model1 = cList[0]
        }
        //try container.mainContext.save()//Trying the suggestion in the comments. It no longer prints ""
        print("Container Done")
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container")
    }
}()



Models

@Model public class Model3 {
    private var amount: Int
    @Relationship(inverse: \Model1.model3) var model1: Model1?
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Model2.model3) var model2: Model2?
    @Relationship var model2Old: Model2?
    
    init(amount: Int, model1: Model1? = nil, model2: Model2? = nil, model2Old: Model2? = nil) {
        self.amount = amount
        self.model1 = model1
        self.model2 = model2
        self.model2Old = model2Old
    }
}

== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:
CrashReportError: PEM crashed due to an uncaught exception

PEM crashed due to an uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`. Reason: -[__NSDictionaryM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000234f20.

Process: PEM[8900]
Date/Time: 2024-04-21 13:54:10 +0000
Log File: <none>


Hi @JoakimDanielson, I can't put the code for models 1 and 2 because I have an error in the form (too much code), but I confirm that the relationships are 1toMany for both: "@Relationship var model3: [Model3]".

Ok then my assumption was incorrect. Did you check the diagnostics?

@JoakimDanielson I try to read report, but I'm not able to understand.
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: PEM [8847].
In diagnostic: crashed due to an uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException. Reason: -[__NSDictionaryM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000234f20.

Wild guess, add a save() call at the end of the tList.forEach so that the relationships  are persisted before using the same objects in another relationship.

@JoakimDanielson Now it doesn't finish creating the container and it doesn't even print the fatal error... it says same error: PEM crashed due to an uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException. Reason: -[__NSDictionaryM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023bfe0.

I tried to reproduce this but there is to much information missing (my preview actually worked but I had to simplify the code)

Can you share the code, that I try to see the differences? Or, if it's not too much, I can give you temporary access to my git repository.

No, you should try to post a reproducible example.
